# How to get the 'Request URL' from http header with python

Tags: url, request

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8ysZ.png)

I would like to scrape a website specially for the Request URL: in the General header.
Unsure of what is need in python to capture this data.

import requests
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

url = 'URL'

headers = {
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
'Accept-Language' : 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
'Referer' : 'URL',
'DNT' : '1',

}

def get_url(args):
network_logs = driver.execute_script("var performance = window.performance || window.mozPerformance || "
"window.msPerformance || window.webkitPerformance || {}; var network = "
"performance.getEntries() || {}; return network;")
for network_log in network_logs:
name = network_log.get("Request URL", "")
if "Request URL" in name:
return name
return False

```
browser.get(url)
```

file_link = WebDriverWait(browser, 1000).until(get_url)

r = requests.get(url,headers=headers)

print(r.text)